# Is factoring complicated functions with let bindings good coding style?

Tags: clojure, coding-style

I often find myself writing functions like this:

```
(defn my-function [arg]
  (let [x (foo arg)
        y (bar x)
        z (baz x)]
    (make-result y z)))
```

So instead of writing `(make-result (bar (foo arg)) (baz (foo arg)))` I split the code into a set of temporary bindings. (Of course, typically the bindings are more complicated than this trivial example.)

I don't particularly like that the core function logic is contained inside the let bindings.

Is there a better convention for writing such sequences of code?

Comment: I *like* your style. If you were writing a complex algebraic expression, you might well factor it into several named sub-expressions. The [`algo.graph` library](https://github.com/clojure/algo.graph) uses this mode of expression throughout. However, it's all opinion, so your question is out of place here. and ought to be EXTERMINATED!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is idiomatic, and `let` is explicitly sequential and expected to be used that way. Especially since this avoids calling `(foo arg)` twice (Clojure is not so pure that the compiler could automatically transform this to a single call to `foo`).